# How to replace specific columns multiple value in Spark Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to replace or update some specific column value in dataframe, as we know  Dataframe is immutable, I am trying to transform in to new dataframe instead of Update or Replacement.

I tried **dataframe.replace** as explained in Spark doc, but it's giving me error as **error: value replace is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame**

I tried below option.For passing multiple value I am passing in array

```
val new_df= df.replace("Stringcolumn", Map(array("11","17","18","10"->"12")))
```

but I am getting error as

**error: overloaded method value array with alternatives**

Help is really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

To access **org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions** such as **replace** you have to call `.na`. So your code should look something like this,

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap

df.na.replace("Stringcolumn", Map(10 -> 12, 11 -> 17))
```

see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html#replace(java.lang.String[],%20java.util.Map)) to get all the list of DataFrameNaFunctions and how to use them